# Not able to persist entity in jpa if extending class with spring AuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have classes’ hierarchy like this

```
public class AccessHistoryJpaDAO extends PaginatedJpaDAO<AccessHistory, Long>
implements AccessHistoryDAO
```

in AccessHistoryJpaDAO I implemented  logIn method which is declared in AccessHistoryDAO interface.

```
public void logIn(AccessHistory entity) throws DAOException
{
    super.save(entity);     
}
```

Then I extends  AuthenticationProcessingFilter of spring

public class CustomAuthenticatingFilter extends AuthenticationProcessingFilter

and overridden method

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws AuthenticationException
```

in this method when I call

```
getAccessHistoryDAO().logIn(entity);
```

hibernate is not able to persist entity but 
when I call direclty

```
getAccessHistoryDAO().save(entity)
```

Above method it is persisting entity, well I try to figure it out but no clue, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One thing i forgot was, there is no exception or odd behaviour of hibernate, it is return back entity with an id which is indication of successfully insert but there is no row in table. But as soon as i called getAccessHistoryDAO().save(entity) there is a row in table.

Comment: Does it throw any exception or entity just don't get persisted?

Comment: In such cases as Ralph mention, there will be no exception but hibernate will not start transaction so no record will be inserted in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a very well known problem with Proxy-AOPs.

I guess you have a `@Transactional` annotation at the `save` method. But this Annotation is only taken in account if the method is invoked from an OTHER spring bean. If it is invoked from the same spring bean (`this.save()`) then the AOP Proxy is not invoked and therefore the Transaction is not started.

You can handle the problem in at least three different ways:

- put an additional `@Transactional` annotation at the `logIn` method, or
- use explicit transaction management instead of declarative,
- use real AspectJ instead of Spring Proxy-AOP  (this is what I do)

Comment: Thanks for your reply actually you are right i missed     @Transactional